# mongotools collection restore Oplog warnings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-oplog

I regularly reinstate prod data into testing environments on MongoDB Atlas. I delete it and perform a mongotools `restore --collection myCollection`. I have good reasons.not to replace the whole dB.

Is there a way to avoid hammering the oplog during such copy and hence generate warnings on the oplog window size?

In the first instance I thought just to disable them, since it doesn't really matter from a backup point of view. However this may cause replica sync issues (which matters little too, due to the nightly nature of the job, but still doesn't feel like I'm doing the right thing).

Thank you.